# $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ continuous at 0; prove $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,g(x)=xf(x)$ differentiable at 0 and find $g'(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Suppose that $f \colon ℝ → ℝ$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Prove that the function $g \colon ℝ → ℝ$ given by $g(x) = xf(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and find $g'(0)$.
I'm honestly confused about what I can do, my teacher said using the definition of derivative might help, however, I can't see how. Here's my attempt anyways:
Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, it must be differentiable at $x=0$. Therefore a scalar multiple of it is also differentiable at $x=0$, so $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.
Second part: $g(x) = xf(x)+f'(x)$. Not sure what to do from here now.

Comment: Do you know the definition of differentiation?

Comment: (1) A function $f$ continuous at a point (say at zero) need not be differentiable at that point. (2) $g(x) = xf(x)$ by assumption, not “$xf(x) + f'(x)$” which doesn’t even exist in general (because of (1)).

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is continuous at $0$ means that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} f(x) = f(0)$. Let $f(0) = L$.

Then:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
g'(0) &=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac {g(h) - g(0)} h \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac {h f(h) - 0 L} h \\
&=& \displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} f(h) \\
&=& L
\end{array}$$

Hence $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g'(0) = L$.

Comment: Your writing style (“$g'(0) = \lim_{h→0} …$”) already assumes $g$ to be differentable at zero, which is what one is trying to show in the first place. At freshman’s and sophomore’s level, this is not only considered bad style, but harmful.

Comment: @k.stm We say that $g$ is differentiable at zero if that limit exists. I'm proving that limit exists. I'll admit that my writing style isn't very formal, but that'll do.

Comment: @k.stm That's needlessly pedantic. It is clear from the computation that the limit exists and hence $g$ is differentiable at $0$ with $g'(0)=L$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I’m just saying: This way, inexperienced students learn to argue that “by L’Hôpital,
$$\lim_{x → 0} \frac{\cos x}{x} = \lim_{x → 0} \frac{-\sin x}{1} = 0.”$$
(And there are more subtle and analogous examples that I don’t remember right now.) I wouldn’t point this out if this was a question at an advanced stage, but I do think this issue matters somewhat for freshman and sophomore level questions. Those who teach should set a good example of *careful* calculation (so students see how this is done and go back to careful calculation if they run into troubles being casual).

Comment: @k.stm I don't really see how your example relates. Your example is simply an incorrect application of a theorem (the hypotheses are not satisfied). Kenny's answer on the other hand is fine: $g$ is differentiable at $0$ (by definition) if the limit exists, and in this case $g'(0)$ equals that limit. Would you think it's okay if $g'(0)$ did not show up at the beginning, but rather at the end $\ldots = L = g'(0)$? If that's the case, I stand by my stance that this is pedantism.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri That’s why I said “there are more … analogous examples”. And no, that still wouldn’t be okay. Starting with “$g’(0) = …$” is also bad, but the core problem here lies in writing “$\lim_{h → 0} …$” before knowing that this limit exists.

Comment: @k.stm Kenny literally proved the limit exists by computing it. That's what the symbol $\lim_{h\to0}$ indicates. I'm not sure we're going to reach an agreement, but I'll just state the essence of my point. I think that in mathematics it is distressingly common to see disproportionate value be given to being *technically right*. There is a difference between rigorous and nitpicky. I think this stance drives many people away from mathematics and generally creates uneasiness. If I had to guess, the people most afraid to say something 'wrong' are all mathematicians. *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* I find it genuinely concerning how many students I've known seem to be truly ashamed of making an incorrect observation.  And I do believe these things are connected. In the end, I think the problem lies in the fact that way too many mathematicians/students would rather be technically correct than understood. I firmly believe mathematicians should strive first and foremost to be understood, with rigor coming in a (very) close second.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Apart from “Since
$$\frac{g(h) - g(0)}{h} = \frac{h·f(h) - 0·f(0)}{h} = f(h) \overset{h → 0}{\longrightarrow} f(0),$$
$g$ is differentiable at zero with $g'(0) = f(0)$” being perfectly understandable (and quite readable), my point is: Freshman students *do* make the mistake of taking the existence of limits for granted as soon as they write “$\lim_{h → 0}$” in front, and using Kenny’s style encourages students to carelessly put “$\lim_{h → 0}$” in front. I’ve seen it happen and I think it’s better to stick with the other style where comfortable.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri And this is not an issue about formal correctness, but about didactics. Also, I think it’s clearer: As a freshman student, I would get confused whenever a tutor would write “$\lim_{h → 0}$” before first establishing that the limit really exists. Especially in lengthy arguments, I would ask myself: “So did we already know that the limit exists or are we still trying to show this?”. Using the non-$\lim$-style makes the structure of a proof clearer.